# What is the profession "Greensman" in 1937?

Tags: england, profession

So I have this marriage certificate from 1937 in Chichester. The profession of the father looks to me to be:

**Greensman**

I might have read the text incorrectly. Here is the source:

[image: Greensman]

I Googled the profession but it talks about film making so I do not think it was that. Can anyone explain what this profession was?

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl I guess that I felt that green screens etc were used in more recent years and not in the 1930s.

Comment: Ah, like noted here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greensman. I just read the word "film-making"!

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl At the moment I have not found the 1939 record that I think is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not believe you've read the text incorrectly, and can suggest 2 possibilities:

1. A greensman associated with the film (and perhaps theatre) industry -- somebody who was responsible for the plants, flowers, landscaping etc.  used on set during filming.
2. A greensman (or greenkeeper) who maintains the greens at a golf source or other sporting facility (perhaps associated with a school)

You could explore the possibilities by (a) looking for matching candidates in the 1939 register; (b) researching the 1930s film industry in the UK to see if the location involved supports an involvement with filming; (c) looking for golf clubs, schools and sports grounds in the relevant area.